# Can't restore iPhone. Not enough space

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm trying to restore an iPhone backup but it's telling me there isn't enough space on the new iPhone. They are both 128 GB.

The old device says its total capacity is 122.35 GB (17.19 GB free). The new one says it's 122.36 GB (119.72 GB free). So what gives?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Are you using a PC to restore the device or another OS / tool / app? Please use the [edit control](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/461495/edit) to make an edit and add these details. Or if you can explain how you're doing this on the device that might help us avoid sending you to Apple Support for support.